# I don't know what's wrong with my syntax

Tags: batch-file

I have a code written below as

```
    set filename=A20150715.1600
    set today=%date:~10,13%%date:~4,2%%date:~7,2%
    set fileday=%filename:~1,8%
    if today == fileday
    (
    echo same
    )
    else
    (
    echo not same
    )
```

but when I run the script, when the code gets to the set fileday part it gives me an error saying incorrect syntax, but appears to accept the value anyways. But then when I try to check the two in the if case it won't echo same, meaning that even though they are the same, they aren't considered the same. It won't even echo not same.

What's wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@echo off
set filename=A20150715.1600
set today=%date:~10,13%%date:~4,2%%date:~7,2%
set fileday=%filename:~1,8%
if %today%==%filename% (
echo same 
) else (
echo not same
)

pause
```

Wrapping `today` and `filename` in %% declares that they are variables. Without it, the program interprets that they are plain text. Also, `else` statements MUST be  on the same line as the `if` statement's closing parenthesis.

To read more about if/else, [click here](http://ss64.com/nt/if.html).

**Note:** For the sake of a good program i added `@echo off` to prevent the command prompt from appearing and `pause` to halt the program when it reaches a conclusion.

Answer (score 0):

1. use `%` to get the variable contents in `if`
2. type `(` on the same line with the previous statement
3. type `else` on the same line with the previous statement

---

```
set filename=A20150715.1600
set filename=A20150715.1600
set today=%date:~10,13%%date:~4,2%%date:~7,2%
set fileday=%filename:~1,8%
if %today%==%fileday% (
    echo same
) else (
    echo not same
)
```